# Когда стоит использовать command bus?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, symfony

Всем привет,
В каких случаях стоит использовать `commandBus`?

Стоит ли использовать его для обычного crud?

Я использую `symfony` и мне нравится компонент форм который он предоставляет.

```
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $command = new CreateCurrencyCommand();
        $form = $this->createForm(CurrencyType::class, $command);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->commandBus->handle($command);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_currency_index');
        }

        return $this->render('admin/currency/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Содержимым формы является `CreateCurrencyCommand` (Обычная DTO которая содержит поля и геттеры/сеттеры) и создание валюты выглядит очень даже не плохо, очень тонкий контроллер и бизнес логика вынесена в отдельный обработчик, который создает сущность и сохраняет её в бд.

Проблема возникла когда я попробовал сделать то же самое для редактирования, главная проблема заключается в данных для формы, так как уже используется `CreateCurrencyCommand` вместо `UpdateCurrencyCommand`. Вот как выглядит метод редактирования без вмешательства команд

```
    public function edit(Request $request, Currency $currency): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(CurrencyType::class, $currency);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_currency_index');
        }

        return $this->render('admin/currency/edit.html.twig', [
            'currency' => $currency,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

И тут я вижу 2 варианта:

1. Сделать универсальную команду без разделения на создание/редактирование/удаление (если делать по такому способу то как команду и обработчики лучше раскладывать по папкам?)
2. Сделать 2 формы для создания и редактирования и для каждой дать свою команду, что делать мне как-то не очень хочется.
3. Не использовать команды при crud операциях.
   Это самый простой пример создания сущности. Для данного случая можно оставить как есть и метод не будет большим, но ведь не каждое создание выглядит так просто.
   Посоветуйте как лучше поступить? И почему? Возможно стоит это делать каким нибудь другим способом который вы знаете.

Answer (score 0):

Этот архитектурный подход («Команда») подразумевает отдачу работы «на сторону» (или outsourcing) без возможности получить результаты работы, как к примеру, возврат у функции. Если также не считать что там возможна асинхронная обработка ваших команд, то, по сути, это просто архитектурный «сахарок», который позволяет вам организовать код для лучшего понимания и использования вне контекста (контроллер, модуль, проект, сервис и т.д